# ZainCash payment method - mobile payment API

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I have magento 1.9
and want to add custom payment method with mobile payment through simple API that the mobile company provide.

Here is the documentation:
https://zaincash.iq/portal/en/web/mfs/integration-with-api

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Right now I think this question is too broad. You already have the docs, you should either try it yourself or hire a developer. I don't think anyone here is going to write all the code for you for free. Please go and try and if you run into specific problems that are Magento related (and not with this API) you could ask them here. If you run into problems with that API, ask your questions at ZainCash support.